# How do I consolidate 2 different users into 1

Tags: support, accounts

I just noticed that I have 2 different accounts with the same ID.  Is there a way to consolidate them into 1?
Clearly, I messed up once at work and created a new user (with the same user ID) rather than logging into my existing one, but that user has a couple questions that I want to retain in my history.